# Laplace transform of pdf of hitting time for square root diffusion

Tags: reference-request, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus

Consider the SDEs
\begin{align}
dX_t&=\alpha X_tdt+\sqrt{v_t}X_tdB_t \\
dv_t&=\eta(\theta-v_t)dt+\xi \sqrt{v_t}dW_t
\end{align}
where $\alpha,\eta,\theta,\xi$ are constants and $\rho$ is the correlation between the standard Brownian motions $B_t$ and $W_t$.

For $a>0$, let $\tau_a=\inf\limits_{t\geq0}\{X_t=a\}$ be the first hitting/passage time.

---

**Question:** Is the Laplace transform of the density function of $\tau_a$ known analytically: $$\mathbb{E}[e^{-s\tau_a}]=?$$

I guess it may be known `semi-analytically,' involving the characteristic function of $\ln(X_t)$?

---

For the special case $\eta=\xi=0$, the process $X_t$ is a geometric Brownian motion and we know that \begin{align*}
\mathbb{E}[e^{-s\tau_a}]=\begin{cases} 
\left(\frac{X_0}{a}\right)^{\beta_1} &\text{if } X_0\leq a \\ 
\left(\frac{X_0}{a}\right)^{\beta_2} &\text{if } X_0\geq a
\end{cases}
\end{align*}
where $\beta_{1,2}$ are roots to a quadratic polynomial derived from the infinitesimal generator of the geometric Brownian motion.